# Superscripts not showing

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am trying to display some calculator functions using FXML and CSS embedded. My goal is to insert  this sign ***"xⁿ"*** and othe calculator's commom operations symbols. My Calculator app doesnt seem to display it after applying the CSS below.

***CSS***

```
.root {
     -fx-background-image: url("background.jpg");
}

*.button {
    -fx-background-color:
        #090a0c,
        linear-gradient(#38424b 0%, #1f2429 20%, #191d22 100%),
        linear-gradient(#20262b, #191d22),
        radial-gradient(center 50% 0%, radius 100%, rgba(114,131,148,0.9), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    -fx-background-radius: 32;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2,3,0;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
    -fx-text-fill: linear-gradient(white, #1fd0d0d0);
    -fx-font-size: 17px;
    -fx-padding: 10 20 10 20;
}

.button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#2A5058, #61a2b1);
}
```

***FXML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="420.0" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.ikhideifidon.calculator.MainController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
    </padding>
   <StackPane prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="200.0">
      <children>
         <Label fx:id="result" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="271.0">
            <font>
               <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Label>
      </children></StackPane>
   <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0">
      <children>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="C">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="±">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="﹪">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="÷">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="#xb2">
            <font>
               <Font size="16.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="sin">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
      </children>
   </HBox>
   <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0">
      <children>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="60.0" text="7">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="60.0" text="8">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="60.0" text="9">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="×">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="In">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="cos">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
      </children>
   </HBox>
   <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0">
      <children>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="60.0" text="4">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="60.0" text="5">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="60.0" text="6">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="-">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="x²">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="tan">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
      </children>
   </HBox>
   <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0">
      <children>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="70.0" text="1">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="70.0" text="2">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="70.0" text="3">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="70.0" text="+">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="70.0" text="√x">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="70.0" text="mod">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
      </children>
   </HBox>
   <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0">
      <children>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="0">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text=".">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="=">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="xⁿ">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
         <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="60.0" text="x!">
            <font>
               <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
      </children>
   </HBox>
</VBox>
```

***The Calculator App***
[image]

Please how can I go about this?
NOTE: I have tried to adjust the size of the fonts.

Comment: They just look like the text is too long for the button. Instead of hard-coding sizes of everything, use a `GridLayout` and configure it so the columns are equal widths (e.g. use `ColumnConstraints` with `percentWidth`) and so the buttons fill the cells. Then the layout mechanism will make sure everything is large enough to hold the text, if at all possible. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html

Comment: Off topic, but I advise using an external CSS stylesheet for styling rather than placing styles like font size directly in the FXML file.

Comment: never-ever hard-code sizing constraints

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `Paddings` to `-fx-padding: 10 5 10 5;` everything looks fine.

[image]

Comment: don't rely on hard-coded sizes to "fix" layout issues - it will break at the slightest change.. instead use an appropriate layout pane